# Having a file extension issue when browsing for files with specific extensions vb script browse for folder

Tags: vbscript

I'm sort of stuck on a project I'm working on for a client.
Below is the code.inside a .vbs file.

The code returns the path to most files however on certain MS office files namely .doc or .docx and .mdb and .aacdb in returns a error.

I can't figure out why.

```
Dim objFolder, objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select the folder and files", &H4000, "0")
If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
   wscript.echo "Folder: " & objFolder.title
   wscript.echo "Full Path: " & objFolder.Self.path 
End If
```

Comment: What error? Please edit your question and add the error details (using text, not images)

Comment: I've removed my comments and added a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2043b32-ea2b-4aa3-b21e-39c2e164e0de/browseforfolder-using-vbs-in-windows-10?forum=ITCG) about this issue, with the consensus that using a BrowseForFolder dialog for files is not a good option. If you're determined to use a `BrowseForFolder` dialog for files, you will need to add `BrowseInPlace` registry entries to extend the list of supported file types. In the example below, text files and docx files have been added:

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

oWSH.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\txtfile\BrowseInPlace","1"
oWSH.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\docxfile\BrowseInPlace","1"

Set oFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select the folder and files", &H4000, "0")
MsgBox oFolder.Self.Path
```

Logically, doc file support would be a "docfile" entry, but that does not work. With enough research and trial and error, there's probably a way to get doc files to work too, but there are better alternatives to BrowseForFolder, so it's probably not worth the effort.

One popular alternative file dialog method is to leverage the MSHTML `input type=file` option. The downside is that the prompt is locked in as **Choose file to upload**. If you can live with that, here's an example that supports [filters](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp):

```
Function BrowseForFileWithFilter(f):BrowseForFileWithFilter=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=10""><input type=file id=f accept="""&f&"""><script>resizeTo(0,0);f.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(f.value);close();</script>""").StdOut.ReadLine():End Function

SelectedFile = BrowseForFileWithFilter(".doc,.docx")
MsgBox SelectedFile
```

Another option is to use my command line [FileDialog](https://lesferch.github.io/FileDialog/) tool. It gives you every possible option and it's completely free. The only downside is that it's a separate exe (but it is very small).

Note: If you're in the process of adding interface elements to your VBS script, it's worth considering changing it to an HTA, so that you have a lot more interface options and aren't locked into a simplistic synchronous approach.

IMO, the best solution, by far, is to purchase a copy of [VBSEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/), and turn your VBS script (or HTML application) into an Exe. Then you get the benefit of the VBSEdit extensions, which include nice file dialogs. It's only $60 for a lifetime license, so, before dismissing a non-free solution, consider what your time is worth and how much time you've already wasted on this issue. I switched my main project from an HTA to a VBSEdit HTML application and it was well worth it. It gives me a proper Exe with proper modal file dialogs, among other things. You also get the same benefits with VBS scripts.